# Is there an equivalent of Cisco IOS' virtual tunnel interfaces in Juniper's JUNOS?

Tags: vpn, cisco, junos

It sounds like Cicso's virtual tunnel interfaces let you run dynamic routing protocols over IPSEC tunnels without GRE (see [here](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/technologies/tk583/tk372/technologies_white_paper0900aecd8029d629.html)). I was wondering if there was an equivalent in Juniper's JUNOS. I didn't see anything in JUNOS' documentation but I'm hoping someone here has used it and knows the same of the feature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

cisco's virtual tunnel interfaces is just cisco's implementation of route based vpn

juniper does route based vpn by default

So like many things, Juniper "just works" when it comes to things Cisco has added on.

Comment: Huh. It does just work. Go figure.